# PHP cropping bottom og the image

Tags: php, image, gd, crop

So I have an image like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOpNt.png and I need to crop out red area. I tried to crop it, but the function is cropping the whole image, from the top and from the bottom. So how to crop only the bottom of the image? The final result is wrong (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqRy5.png) Here is the code:

```
function getWidth() {
    return imagesx($this->image);
}

function getHeight() {
    return imagesy($this->image);
}

function cutTheBottom($width, $height){
    $height = $this->getHeight() - 55;
    $width = $this->getWidth();

    $x = ($this->getWidth() / 2) - ($width / 2);
    $y = ($this->getHeight() / 2) - ($height / 2);

    return $this->cut($x, $y, $width, $height);
}

function cut($x, $y, $width, $height)
{
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image, true);

    imagecopy($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height);

    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

Comment: What is `$this->image` to start with, it it an image resource? When you try to getHeight and getWidth it might be returning 0 (false) if not.

Comment: Yes, $this->image is the source of the image. Creating like this `$this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg(...);`

Comment: k, next is why are you starting the dest_x and dest_y as $x and $y. Aren't you just offsetting there? have you tried  ` imagecopy($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);`